# How to connect online services (specifically Squarespace and Shipstation) to sync order details beyond their provided APIs

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, squarespace

I have an e-commerce store on Squarespace, and I use Shipstation to fulfill my orders. The store sells uniquely numbered pieces of art so tight inventory control is a must, which I recently inputed into Squarespace so it was all in one space and automatically updated every time someone buys a piece. I also offer the art in one of two colored frames though, so with each order I need to collect the frame color choice as a custom product form (not as a separate SKU). Upon making this change in Squarespace, I realized this information wasn't passing through the order API to Shipstation so I have been manually typing into the Shipstation order tickets which color frame each order has :(.

I asked Squarespace what the issue was, and they said that the custom product form data isn't shared through the API sadly. I'm looking for any way to close this data loop between Squarespace and Shipstation but am not quite sure where to start. I've tried working around it but every option I know is still handicapped by the Squarespace Order API's lack of sharing.

Answer (score 0):

One option (which you may have already considered and are hoping to avoid) is to create separate [product variants](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206540687-Adding-basic-product-variants) for each artwork/frame-color combination.

The other (theoretically possible) option gets rather technically complex and involves:

1. Using the [ShipStation API](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206540687-Adding-basic-product-variants)
2. Using client-side code on the order confirmation page OR using Zapier (via the confirmation email) to send the custom form data to an endpoint to parse and send the data to the ShipStation API
3. Setup, coding, and maintenance of said endpoint (might be possible using Google Apps Script).